# device not accepting address 18, error -71

Tags: linux, linux-mint, usb, ethernet

I am using a USB to ethernet converter to connect my laptop to a raspberry pi. But the kernel log shows

```
USB: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

I have used this device previously without any problem.

The full log output and the output of `lspci` and `lsusb` looks as follows:

**dmesg:**

```
blackfly@BlackFly:~$ dmesg
[    0.035433] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)

[    1.494940] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.494945] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.496029] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000081109810
[    1.496036] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.496236] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.496237] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.496238] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.496239] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.496240] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.496356] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.496375] hub 1-0:1.0: 12 ports detected
[    1.497671] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.497674] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.497676] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.497712] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.497713] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.497714] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.497715] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.497716] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.497811] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.497825] hub 2-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.498390] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.502097] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.502421] rtc_cmos 00:03: RTC can wake from S4
[    1.502946] rtc_cmos 00:03: registered as rtc0
[    1.502959] rtc_cmos 00:03: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    1.502965] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.503004] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.503068] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.40.0-ioctl (2019-01-18) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.503086] platform eisa.0: Probing EISA bus 0
[    1.503087] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    1.503088] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    1.503089] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    1.503090] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    1.503091] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    1.503092] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    1.503093] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    1.503094] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    1.503094] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    1.503095] platform eisa.0: EISA: Detected 0 cards
[    1.503098] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    1.503381] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
[    1.503418] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.503421] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    1.504386] battery: ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    1.510874] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    1.547192] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[    1.547422] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.553696] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    1.553718] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.553789] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.554153] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    1.554183] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0xca
[    1.554329] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
[    1.554338] sched_clock: Marking stable (1553817954, 507665)->(1561215563, -6889944)
[    1.554484] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.554494] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.556145] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: c209d4e4513ddb6584e17c46859deb0bc3f91652'
[    1.556172] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    1.562232] Key type big_key registered
[    1.562238] Key type trusted registered
[    1.565523] Key type encrypted registered
[    1.565527] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    1.567475] integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
[    1.567514] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17c55af53'
[    1.567515] integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
[    1.567540] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a1bd4'
[    1.567540] integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
[    1.567555] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Acer Database: 84f00f5841571abd2cc11a8c26d5c9c8d2b6b0b5'
[    1.567556] integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:db
[    1.568885] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Pegatron SecureFlash: fef77a732921f0854b4d5405bdb3276d'
[    1.570792] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
[    1.597945] No architecture policies found
[    1.597956] evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
[    1.597957] evm: security.selinux
[    1.597958] evm: security.SMACK64
[    1.597958] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
[    1.597958] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
[    1.597959] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
[    1.597959] evm: security.apparmor
[    1.597960] evm: security.ima
[    1.597960] evm: security.capability
[    1.597961] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    1.599038] PM:   Magic number: 8:24:64
[    1.599242] rtc_cmos 00:03: setting system clock to 2020-02-12T06:04:44 UTC (1581487484)
[    1.600383] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2040K
[    1.600763] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2660K
[    1.611829] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 22528k
[    1.612379] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2008K
[    1.612670] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1476K
[    1.622167] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    1.622168] x86/mm: Checking user space page tables
[    1.631452] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    1.631454] Run /init as init process
[    1.726539] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[    1.773008] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.775739] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    1.786162] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x2 impl SATA mode
[    1.786166] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
[    1.786637] scsi host0: ahci
[    1.788149] scsi host1: ahci
[    1.788220] ata1: DUMMY
[    1.788227] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xb112e000 port 0xb112e180 irq 125
[    1.818288] checking generic (a0000000 7f0000) vs hw (a0000000 10000000)
[    1.818290] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    1.818352] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    1.819383] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.819383] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.820217] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    1.820775] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    1.834515] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20190619 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.837054] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    1.837442] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
[    1.840878] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.843043] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.843044] fbcon: Deferring console take-over
[    1.843046] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    1.994098] usb 1-6: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x3 has wMaxPacketSize 0, skipping
[    1.994100] usb 1-6: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x83 has wMaxPacketSize 0, skipping
[    1.994103] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    1.994104] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.104702] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.106379] ata2.00: ATA-10: Micron_1100_MTFDDAV256TBN,  M0MA020, max UDMA/133
[    2.106381] ata2.00: 500118192 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    2.109429] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.119628] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
[    2.119952] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Micron_1100_MTFD A020 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.120257] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[    2.120269] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.120296] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 500118192 512-byte logical blocks: (256 GB/238 GiB)
[    2.120304] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.120306] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.120319] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.120395] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[    2.121972]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5
[    2.122483] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[    2.122593] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.125255] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.279955] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5f7, bcdDevice=92.26
[    2.279957] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.279958] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[    2.279959] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
[    2.408294] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.472249] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2399.989 MHz
[    2.472257] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x22982cf31bf, max_idle_ns: 440795239146 ns
[    2.472301] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.556687] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129, bcdDevice=39.60
[    2.556689] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.556690] usb 1-8: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[    2.556691] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Generic
[    2.556692] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
[    2.684249] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.836062] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1c7a, idProduct=0570, bcdDevice=10.41
[    2.836064] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.836065] usb 1-9: Product: EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor
[    2.836066] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: EgisTec
[    2.836067] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: \xc2\x97009A26B
[    2.843296] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtsx_usb
[    4.007772] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    4.028421] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    4.030797] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <BlackFly>.
[    4.137970] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    4.138051] systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[    4.138281] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.138294] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    4.138475] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    4.138555] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    4.138609] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[    4.167233] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    4.173726] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    4.177222] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    4.246590] systemd-journald[419]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    4.477780] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.483670] idma64 idma64.0: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[    4.487847] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.492293] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.492677] idma64 idma64.1: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[    4.501638] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA7DB5:00: i2c-SYNA7DB5:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.501674] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA7DB5:00: i2c-SYNA7DB5:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.561383] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    4.567636] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    4.580082] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.580099] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    4.580101] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.580104] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.580106] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.580109] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.582598] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    4.589661] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.594791] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop ACPI-WMI Extras
[    4.594824] acer_wmi: Function bitmap for Communication Button: 0x801
[    4.624909] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    4.624910] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    4.625597] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.628508] input: Acer WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input5
[    4.644489] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[    4.654702] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[    4.661455] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.663744] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD WebCam (04f2:b5f7)
[    4.685688] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[    4.685704] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[    4.685706] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[    4.685708] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    4.685807] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input6
[    4.685881] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.685883] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    4.686149] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[    4.686150] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[    4.686151] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[    4.686152] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[    4.686153] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[    4.703896] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    4.704110] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    4.727609] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 34:f6:4b:ed:dd:0c
[    4.741575] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    4.741576] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    4.788258] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.788995] thermal thermal_zone2: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[    4.831862] mei_hdcp mei::b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04:01: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[    4.835652] input: SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-5/i2c-SYNA7DB5:00/0018:06CB:7DB7.0001/input/input7
[    4.840544] input: SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-5/i2c-SYNA7DB5:00/0018:06CB:7DB7.0001/input/input8
[    4.840866] hid-generic 0018:06CB:7DB7.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7] on i2c-SYNA7DB5:00
[    4.918161] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.922527] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.953881] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.953884] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    4.953885] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    4.953886] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    4.975959] input: SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-5/i2c-SYNA7DB5:00/0018:06CB:7DB7.0001/input/input11
[    4.976077] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:7DB7.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7] on i2c-SYNA7DB5:00
[    4.992119] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC255: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.992121] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.992122] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.992123] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.992124] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    4.992125] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
[    4.992126] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    5.002453] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[    5.019544] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[    5.047033] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[    5.047115] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[    5.047191] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[    5.047256] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[    5.047334] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[    5.047407] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[    5.395857] Adding 2097148k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:2097148k SSFS
[    5.821730] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    5.857306] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.332163] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=710 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.333228] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=707 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.333231] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=707 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.333233] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=707 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.333236] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=707 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.333282] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=706 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.333285] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=706 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.334337] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=711 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.334710] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=713 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.335315] audit: type=1400 audit(1581487489.229:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=709 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.028963] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.028965] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.028969] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.147884] fbcon: Taking over console
[    9.181135] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   31.859414] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   31.859422] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   31.859427] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  351.162440] wlp1s0: authenticate with c8:d7:79:a0:0e:97
[  351.167457] wlp1s0: send auth to c8:d7:79:a0:0e:97 (try 1/3)
[  351.171692] wlp1s0: authenticated
[  351.172028] wlp1s0: associate with c8:d7:79:a0:0e:97 (try 1/3)
[  351.180151] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from c8:d7:79:a0:0e:97 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  351.185802] wlp1s0: associated
[  351.215236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[ 3759.604247] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[ 3760.690474] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 3760.818495] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3761.054504] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3761.290480] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 3761.418498] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3761.654513] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3761.762496] usb usb1-port5: attempt power cycle
[ 3762.414489] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 3762.414668] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3762.622674] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3762.830490] usb 1-5: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[ 3762.958495] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 3762.958676] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3763.166693] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3763.374502] usb 1-5: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[ 3763.374596] usb usb1-port5: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 4401.008664] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 4401.170983] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=2340, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 4401.170986] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4401.170989] usb 1-5: Product: x705w
[ 4401.170990] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: HP
[ 4401.170992] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: E6006A37F2506747
[ 4401.207294] usb-storage 1-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4401.207646] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[ 4401.207805] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 4401.210840] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 4402.759049] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     hp       x705w            PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4402.760210] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 30965760 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[ 4402.760280] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 4402.761387] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4402.761391] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 4402.762619] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 4402.762629] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4402.768481]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[ 4402.771821] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4402.972527] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 4402.973906] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 4402.980917] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
[ 4469.524289] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 4479.444785] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 4479.572796] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4479.808789] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4480.044733] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 4480.172763] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4480.408749] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4480.516823] usb usb1-port5: attempt power cycle
[ 4481.168659] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 4481.168848] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4481.376834] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4481.584631] usb 1-5: device not accepting address 14, error -71
[ 4481.712616] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[ 4481.712802] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4481.920776] usb 1-5: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4482.128619] usb 1-5: device not accepting address 15, error -71
[ 4482.128681] usb usb1-port5: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 4637.678448] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 0
[ 5147.480104] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
[ 5150.074772] mmc0: card never left busy state
[ 5150.074778] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[ 5151.519835] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
[ 5151.531118] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL08G 7.40 GiB 
[ 5151.538527]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[ 5151.846891] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[ 5151.960779] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[ 5152.195074] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 5247.345816] mmc0: card aaaa removed
[ 5287.612780] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[ 5319.205346] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 5319.333456] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5319.569530] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5319.805465] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 5319.933654] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5320.169576] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5320.277624] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 5320.929776] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 5320.929985] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5321.138173] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5321.345735] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 18, error -71
[ 5321.474085] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 5321.474281] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5321.682348] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5321.890190] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 19, error -71
[ 5321.890277] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

**lspci:**

```
blackfly@BlackFly:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

**lsusb:**

```
blackfly@BlackFly:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c7a:0570 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5f7 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your title mentions "error -71" just as your log output does, but the first error message you quoted contains "error -110". Could you comment on whether that error still occurs, because that may point to a device drawing too much power from the USB port (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110) e.g.). Can you tell if the USB-Ethernet converter worked fine before _on the same machine_ as you are trying now, or if the successfull uses were at a different computer?

Comment: @AdminBee That's my mistake. Actually, its error-71. Yes, it worked fine in the same machine, during that time I was using ubuntu 16.04. Right now, I am using Linux mint. That's the only difference.

Comment: Are you using an USB extender? A hub? Did you tried on another computer with the same OS? [Seems related](https://askubuntu.com/q/262141/349837) to a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [blog article](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error), it might be a hardware issue.
The USB device might try to protect itself when it draws an over-current.

The proposed solutions vary from trying another cable or turning the computer off, waiting and turning it back on again.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/460353)

Comment: The important take-away from the linked article is just that it might a hardware issue, that it might be a protection against over-currents and that the solution might be turning it off and on again. So, I thought I added all the necessary information, so, what are you missing? I'll be happy to improve my answer where possible.